# Changing variables in namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I want to declare an array inside a namespace, then from another file, define it, and from a third file, access it after it is defined. Can anyone help me? btw, i'm open to using either `int[]` or `std::array`.

```
//name.h
#pragma once
namespace Info {
    int arr[2];
    array<int, 2> arra;
}


//file1.cpp
#include "name.h"
using namespace Info;

arr = {10, 9}
arra = {10, 9}

//main.cpp
#include "name.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    cout<<arr[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You can use either raw arrays or `std::array`, although the latter is often considered preferable in C++.  Declare them as `extern` in the header file, and define them (e.g. `int Info::arr[] = {10,9}`  or `std::array<int, 2> Info::arra {10,9};` or `namespace Info {int arr[2] = {10,9};}`) exactly once in a single source file in your project.   They can then be accessed by any source file that includes the header.    Also, don't use `using namespace std` in a header - even a basic search will turn up explanations about why that is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code could look like this

```
// header file
namespace Info
{
     extern int arr[2];
}

// file1.cpp
namespace Info
{
     int arr[2] = { 2, 3 };
}
```

Prepending the `extern` keyword makes it a declaration that is not a definition (it is not permitted to have multiple definitions).

If you are OK with having the initializer in the header file then the code could be simplified to (since C++17):

```
// header file
namespace Info
{
    inline int arr[2] = { 2, 3 };
}
```

and no other definition required.  The `std::array` version would work the same way.